# Logcat logs continuously on device

Tags: android, debugging, device, logcat

Yesterday, logCat suddenly started to log numerous device-events, once the device is connected. Before, it just logged whatever I logged for debugging purposes in my app. Does anybody know, what I did to enable this behavior? And how to disable it again?

Comment: seems, like it did behave faulty during the last weeks and is now suddenly doing what it's supposed to. solar flare seems about right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set-up logcat "fliters" to filter out messages only from your application.
You can set filters based on tags, pid, etc..

Use this link for more info as to how to setup logcat filters:
[filtering logcat output](http://jtomlinson.blogspot.in/2010/04/android-ddms-and-formatting-logcat.html)

Answer (score 0):

You must have changed the **filter** of your LogCat to **verbose**.

You can change the filter of the messages to be displayed on the LogCat by selecting the drop down list on the top right hand corner of your LogCat window.